# OpenSSL Error messages: error:14095126 unexpected eof while reading

Tags: php, laravel, youtube

**Description** 
This error:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14095126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading
```

returns when:

```
$file = file_get_contents($url['url'], false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

Video to download:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5NzAksjfDI

*Extract the video id:*

```
$video_id = $yt->extractVideoId(implode($url));
```

*Get the downloadable url*

```
$links = $yt->getDownloadLinks($video_id, $selector = 'video');
```

*Get the array key for the specified video quality etc.*

```
$arrayindex = array_search('mp4, video, 1080p, audio', array_column($links, 'format'));
```

*Set $url to array*

```
$url = $links[$arrayindex];
```

*Disable SSL*

```
$arrContextOptions=array( "ssl"=>array( "verify_peer"=>false, "verify_peer_name"=>false, ), );
```

*Get the file from the url*

```
$video = file_get_contents($url['url'], false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

*Send the video back to front end*

```
return view('convert', [ 'url' => $url['url'], 'quality' => $url['format'], ]);
```

**Expected behavior:** 
The video gets downloaded 
**Actual behavior:**

I get this error:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14095126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading
```

The code stops.

**Version** 
The latest version of: 
https://github.com/Athlon1600/youtube-downloader/blob/master/src/YouTubeDownloader.php

**Additional Information** 
This code is in the laravel framework, the code here is in the UrlController. This is a local development server, this error also shows up when the firewall is disabled. All the functions used in my code are in the YouTubeDownloader.php file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well and was able to follow up a little deeper into @Huzaifa99's recommendations.

In my case, I was running a Laravel app with PHP 7.4.5 on Windows. There is apparently an issue with OpenSSL v1.1.1e, possibly just with Windows. Installing the latest build of PHP 7.4.6+ fixed my issues. Specifically, the replacing the file `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`.

Comment: I confirm the issue for PHP 7.4.5 on Windows. I've upgraded to PHP 7.4.10 and works.

Comment: I had faced the same issue for PHP 7.4.5 .. I downloaded latest libssl-1_1-x64.dll file and replaced inside PHP folder. It solved my issue !!!

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem.I suspect you are using Xampp-Windows-7.4.5.In that case `file_get_contents()` function gives the SSL error on laravel.It works on simple(core) php on my side though.

### Things You Can Try.

1. Use Curl instead of `file_get_contents()`.You can create a custom function that would work in the same manner(with SSL enabled) like so.

```
function file_get_content_curl ($url) 
{
    // Throw Error if the curl function does'nt exist.
    if (!function_exists('curl_init'))
    { 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Then you can call the function like this.

```
$data = file_get_content_curl($url);
$save = file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

2. Disable/Uninstall Skpye.As skpye uses port 80/443(https) ,if you are using apache on port 80 try switching to port 8080 or uninstalling skpye if you dont use it.That might also solve your issue.
3. Downgrade to Xampp-Windows-7.2.3 if you want to use `file_get_contents()` function.This also solved the issue for me.

Comment: I had the same problem with simplexml_load_url. Using a curl-wrapper and changing to simplexml_load_string solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the problem here on Windows 10 with php 7.4.9 and apache v2.4.33.
Although I've updated php to the latest php version (v.7.4.11) the issue did still exist.
It turned out that openssl v1.1.1e which came with apache caused the error. After updating to Apache v2.4.46 with openssl v1.1.1h the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem on Windows and I found this information:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-notes

> Warning
> When using SSL, Microsoft IIS will violate the protocol by closing the connection without sending a close_notify indicator. PHP will report this as "SSL: Fatal Protocol Error" when you reach the end of the data. To work around this, the value of error_reporting should be lowered to a level that does not include warnings. PHP can detect buggy IIS server software when you open the stream using the https:// wrapper and will suppress the warning. When using fsockopen() to create an ssl:// socket, the developer is responsible for detecting and suppressing this warning.

I tried to temporary set `error_reporting(0);` and it worked for me, I got the response from remote server.

But I should use other solution for my case. Maybe this info will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

A less brutal version of @SpecDrum's solution worked for me on PHP 8.1.2. The OpenSSL error is represented in PHP as a warning. So it's enough to ignore warnings (temporarily):

```
$error_level = error_reporting();
error_reporting($error_level & ~E_WARNING);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I solved it by copying the libssl-1_1-x64.dll dll from the php folder into the apache bin folder