# OpenSSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, jetty

I'm trying to setup a new https connector for my webserver but I'm receiving "OpenSSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading" whenever I call the endpoints via https. I receive success responses over http:80, but errors on https:443.

Running on Ubuntu 22.04, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Jetty 11.0.11, JVM target 1.8.

I'm attempting to hit the endpoint from the same machine using wget. The web server is running in another tmux window.

```
wget https://localhost:443/
--{timestamp}--  https://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

As per other stack overflow posts, I've tried:

[Updating my packges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627218/openssl-error-messages-error0a000126ssl-routinesunexpected-eof-while-readin)

[Updating my openssl.cnf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405100/i-have-problem-with-new-ubuntu-22-04-and-openssl-3-0-2)

I found [this](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18574) post but I still don't exactly understand the crux of the issue.

Is this error a red herring or actually a problem? Do I need to use a different combination of Ubuntu/OpenSSL? Do I need to use a different version of Jetty?

Comment: Your combination of Jetty 11.0.11 and JVM 1.8 is impossible.  Jetty 11 requires Java 11 minimum.

Comment: Also, SSL/TLS does not work (anymore) with localhost (or ip addresses) due to changes in Java itself, you have to use a hostname, and that hostname needs to exist in the certificate you use on the server side.